# Switch from Python 3.4.2 to Python 2.7.1 OSX

Tags: python, macos

I got an issue with my following demand. First of all i'm a total newbie, so please don't be too rude with me ;) I did install Python 3.4.2 along with PyCharm once (recommendation of a friend), but found a promising tutorial now, which recommends Python 2.7.1 badly, working with the Terminal and TextWrangler --> http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/. Somehow i didn't figure out how to uninstall 3.4.2 or switch to 2.7.1, 'cause the terminal keeps saying i'm still in 3.4.2. I did some research in the web, but got really confused and couldn't find any matching issue to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it can be confusing, you can have both a v2.x and a 3.x version installed on your system. If you have installed a python 2.7.1 after your python 3.4.2, you should be able to run your python 2.7.1, just type python2 in place of python.

Try out :

```
python --version
python2 --version
```

to check which version are installed.

Comment: no problem ;)  Just don't get confused if you keep both on one system.